# How can I split a string with no delimeter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, split

I need to import CSV file which contains all values in one column although it should be on 3 different columns.

The value I want to split is looking like this "2020-12-30 13:17:00Mojito5.5". I want to look like this: "2020-12-30 13:17:00 Mojito 5.5"

I tried different approaches to splitting it but I either get the error " Dataframe object has no attribute 'split' or something similar.

Any ideas how I can split this?

Comment: Can the third value, in the example given, "Mojito" end in a number? If so, I don't think you can reliably split it from the last value, unless the width of the last value (5.5) is known.

Comment: Exactly. How do you know where to split? I get the date, but how do you know that it isn't `["Mojito5.", "5"]`?

Comment: No, it's ending as I mentioned in the post. I know where to split as i have other CSV files with the same structure but formatted on different columns

Comment: It's representing transactions, product, price

Comment: can a product name include numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you always want to add spaces around a word without special characters and numbers you can use this regex:

```
def add_spaces(m):
  return f' {m.group(0)} '

import re
s = "2020-12-30 13:17:00Mojito5.5"
re.sub('[a-zA-Z]+', add_spaces, s)
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use a regex approach here:

```py
inp = "2020-12-30 13:17:00Mojito5.5"
m = re.findall(r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})(\w+?)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', inp)
print(m)  # [('2020-12-30 13:17:00', 'Mojito', '5.5')]
```